# Can't change a value in my array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, background-thread

In my program I am holding the pixel data of a `UIImage` in a basic C array:

```
// It can be UInt8 as it is greyscaled, values can only be 0-255
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UInt8 *imageData;
```

Now in my greyscaling algorithm I initialize it:

```
self.imageData = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * width * height);
```

then I fill in the data as I greyscale. This works. However, in a later algorithm I go through and make values either 0 or 255 through some magic. I thought that was working fine... but a later algorithm looking for these values was getting 1's and 3's. So I went and threw this in right after I change the value from 0-255 to be either 0 or 255:

```
// Magic loop. Starts with current value at pixelIndex, gets curVal. 
self.imageData[pixelIndex] = curVal;
NSAssert(self.imageData[pixelIndex] != curVal, @"Whattt");
```

And lo and behold it isn't actually changing the value of my array. Is there something I'm missing? Are these arrays a one time set and then they become readonly? I know NSArrays are like that, but this is just a simple C pointer-based array... or are they the same?

Whatever the reason, how can I make it so I can properly alter these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine. I think your problem is just that you have your assertion backwards — the condition is supposed to be an expression that you want to be *true*, so currently you are asserting "After I set `self.imageData[pixelIndex]` to be `curVal`, it should not be equal to `curVal`." Instead, that should be:

```
NSAssert(self.imageData[pixelIndex] == curVal, @"Whattt");
```

BTW, when doing this sort of assertion, I always think it's helpful to include the expected and actual values so you can see what's going on. In this case, you could do:

```
NSAssert3(self.imageData[pixelIndex] == curVal, @"Image data at pixel index %d should have been %d, but instead was %d", pixelIndex, curVal, self.imageData[pixelIndex]);
```

This would make it more obvious that the values actually are equal and something is going wrong in your equality check.

Comment: Oh.. well damn. Thank you, back to the debugging drawing board!